# Flutter wrapping Row in SingleChildScrollview ruins spaceBetween

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I have a`Row` of buttons which have a parent of `SingleChildScrollView`, horizontally.
After wrapping the `SingleChildScrollView` the elements of the row don't respect the `mainAxisAlignment`, specifically spaceBetween, they are together with not space in between...

How can I make the spaceBetween work again?

```
SingleChildScrollView(
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
    children: const [
      TransportModeButton(
        iconPath: 'images/icons/walking_icon.png',
        text: 'Walking',
      ),
      TransportModeButton(
        iconPath: 'images/icons/bicycle_icon.png',
        text: 'Bike & eScooter',
      ),
      TransportModeButton(
        iconPath: 'images/icons/public_transport_icon.png',
        text: 'Public transport',
      )
    ],
  ),
),
```

Comment: Try to wrap your `TransportModeButton` inside `Expanded` or `Flexible` Widget hope its help to you.

Comment: Unfotunately it doesn't work... I get an width constrainsts are unbounded error...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can solve it by wrapping your `Row` inside a `BoxConstraints` like:

```
Container(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            child: ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(
                maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              ),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                children: const [
                  Text("test1"),
                  Text("test2"),
                  Text("test3"),
                ],
              ),
            )),
      ),
```

Edit:

to get the constraints from the parents for your `SingleChildsScrollView` you can do so using `LayoutBuilder`, so the code would look like:

```
LayoutBuilder(
                builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
              return SingleChildScrollView(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  child: ConstrainedBox(
                    constraints: BoxConstraints(
                      maxWidth: constraints.maxWidth,
                    ),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                      children: const [
                        Text("test1"),
                        Text("test2"),
                        Text("test3"),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ));
            })
```

Comment: if you limit the width to the width of the screen , why even use SCSV?

Comment: You're right that only solves the problem in the example, I think the only solution would be to generate spacing while building, or even by adding padding or margin to the children.

Comment: Nothing happens if I add the ContrainedBox... Still no space between

Comment: did you set the `maxWidth` ? 
the above code  would give you something like below, I tested it on DartPad.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EEU7LixVT5ad_SBwGu0iJx6vnumRqkFR/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Yeah sorry, I would need to somehow make a ConstrainedBox with the width of the parent and not of the entire context... I get some space between but to much...

Comment: I edited the solution to solve this issue

Comment: @tareqalbeesh I just noticed now that doing this causes the scroll to fail, so If I resize my window to make that widget scrollable, then it just gives me an overflow without making it scrollable, it's like not having SCSV

Comment: It seems that adding 
BoxConstraints(
                        minWidth: constraints.maxWidth)

makes it work again

Comment: Yea, please replace "maxWidth: constraints.maxWidth" by "maxWidth: constraints.minWidth," in the example above.

Answer (score 0):

When you wrap your Row with SCSV, there is actually no width to the row, since it is infinite.

It does not rely on the width of the screen or any other width of to calculate the space between.

If you really want to enable the space between I would suggest 2 ways:

- To wrap the Row with a Container/SizedBox/BoxConstraints and give it a width.
- To add SizedBox / wrap your TransportModeButton with Padding, which will create the spaces, manually, between the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Row/Column takes as much **space as needed**, meaning it can go beyond available height if need be and if there are no constraints.

Your row is taking the needed space and not more. Hence, the MainAxisAlignment is actually working(but not how we want to). Put a SizedBox with width for a space if you want.

My advice is provided is use ListView if you know how many widgets are available and if you're not using the whole screen for this only.

### Single Child Scroll View

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(),
  body: SafeArea(
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: const [
          Icon(
            Icons.nordic_walking,
            size: 50,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 20,
          ),
          Icon(
            Icons.nordic_walking,
            size: 50,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 20,
          ),
          Icon(
            Icons.nordic_walking,
            size: 50,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 20,
          ),
          Icon(
            Icons.nordic_walking,
            size: 50,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 20,
          ),
          Icon(
            Icons.nordic_walking,
            size: 50,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 20,
          ),
          Icon(
            Icons.nordic_walking,
            size: 50,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 20,
          ),
          Icon(
            Icons.nordic_walking,
            size: 50,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 20,
          ),
          Icon(
            Icons.nordic_walking,
            size: 50,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 20,
          ),
          Icon(
            Icons.nordic_walking,
            size: 50,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 20,
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

### ListView

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(),
  body: SafeArea(
    child: ListView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      children: const [
        Icon(
          Icons.nordic_walking,
          size: 50,
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 20,
        ),
        Icon(
          Icons.nordic_walking,
          size: 50,
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 20,
        ),
        Icon(
          Icons.nordic_walking,
          size: 50,
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 20,
        ),
        Icon(
          Icons.nordic_walking,
          size: 50,
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 20,
        ),
        Icon(
          Icons.nordic_walking,
          size: 50,
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 20,
        ),
        Icon(
          Icons.nordic_walking,
          size: 50,
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 20,
        ),
        Icon(
          Icons.nordic_walking,
          size: 50,
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 20,
        ),
        Icon(
          Icons.nordic_walking,
          size: 50,
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 20,
        ),
        Icon(
          Icons.nordic_walking,
          size: 50,
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 20,
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: I need a constrainedBox that inherits it's width from the parent and not the width of the entire context

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `singlechildscrollview`(SCSW) to counter the spacing scenario. It seems like a bad Ux for users to scroll the tile. You can let flow vertically using something like `softwrap`. If you still want to use SCSW then you can try to put constraints on SCSW by wrapping the child of SCSW in `ConstrainedBox`.

`constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width)`

Comment: I need a constrained box with the size of the parent... Which is actually a flexible column